# stop twitter bootstrap carousel navigation for cycling

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Inside the carousal nav, I have  `<a class="carousel-control right" href="#howToBuyCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>`. Jow do I disable going to the next slide, if I am already at the last slide. The same goes if I am at the first slide, I want to disable going left to go to the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attain this functionality by manually checking for the the current active slide in the 'slide' event handler

```
//this function gets called whenever carousel slides

$('#myCarousel').bind('slide', function(){

   var idx = $('#myCarousel .item.active').index();



   if(idx == yourCarouselLength - 1){

     //you have reached the end

     var next = $('#yourCarouselNext');

     // make your button inactive and remove any click handlers if present (pseudocode)

     next.addClass('inactive');

     //or stop automatic cycling, or however you want your carousel to behave


   }else if(idx == 0){

     //you are at the start

     var prev = $('#yourCarouselPrev');

     // make your button inactive and remove any click handlers if present (pseudocode)

     prev.addClass('inactive');

     //or stop automatic cycling, or however you want your carousel to behave

   }


});
```

Here `'#yourCarouselPrev'` and `'#yourCarouselNext'` are ids of your carousel navigation buttons.

Comment: for some reason setting the class to inactive, simply doesn't disable the button..

Comment: The class inactive was just a pointer to how you can proceed. You could manually add an 'inactive' class and remove any attached clicked handlers present etc